VNRecognizeTextRequest fails but can select text in Preview.app
I'm using VNRecognizeTextRequest in an OCR server which accepts images over TCP, performs OCR, and returns the extracted text. The goal is to support all languages but having issues with Chinese.
Overall it works perfectly but there are some images that return zero observation results, ie, OCR fails.
However, if I open those images in Preview, I can select and copy the text to the clipboard. I assume that the MacOs Preview app uses the same VNRecognize OCR framework so it is confusing why OCR succeeds in Preview but fails when using VNRecognizeTextRequest in a Swift program.
Here are two images showing that I can select and copy text from the image in Preview.app:


Environment is MacOS 15.0.1 (It is a MacOS app, not iOS)
Here's the code.  I've tried various combinations of VNRecognizeTextRequest.usesLanguageCorrection and  VNRecognizeTextRequest.recognitionLanguages but will fail on the two images above.
Any suggestions on what to change to have the program match the behaviour of Preview.app?  I'll put the pristine images on the bottom of this post.
public func doOcr(image: CGImage, outStrings: inout [String]) async -> Bool
{
    var ret = true
    
    let ocrRequest = VNRecognizeTextRequest(completionHandler: ocrCompleteCb)
    ocrRequest.recognitionLevel = .accurate
    ocrRequest.automaticallyDetectsLanguage = true
    ocrRequest.customWords = ["…", "᠁", "..."]
    ocrRequest.usesLanguageCorrection = false
    print("usesLanguageCorrection: \(ocrRequest.usesLanguageCorrection)")
    
    //ocrRequest.recognitionLanguages = ["zh-Hant"];
    
    let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: image)
    
    do
    {
        try imageRequestHandler.perform([ocrRequest])
        outStrings = mOcrResults
    }
    catch
    {
        outStrings.append("\(error)")
        ret = false
        print("OCR Error: \(error)")
    }

    return ret
 }


 private func ocrCompleteCb(request: VNRequest, error: Error?)
 {
     mOcrResults.removeAll()

     // Handle the recognition results
     guard let observations = request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation] else
     {
         print("Unexpected observation type.")
         return
     }
 
     // <<< Zero observations found on OCR failure >>>
     mLogger.consoleLogMsg("ocrCompleteCb \(observations.count) observations")
     
     for observation in observations
     {
         let topCandidate = observation.topCandidates(1).first
     
         if let recognizedText = topCandidate?.string
         {
             mLogger.consoleLogMsg("Found: \(recognizedText)")
             mOcrResults.append(recognizedText)
         }
     }
 }

[


By shear luck I found that adding a white margin around the image the VNRecognizeTextRequest would work!
The size of the margin around the text seems to matter. If is too small or too large the text is not recognized.  I haven't yet found the sweet spot for the border size. For this particular image, 40 pixels works.

In addition, I set the following options for VNRecognizeTextRequest:
    ocrRequest.recognitionLanguages = ["zh-Hans", "zh-Hant"] // ["en-US", "zh-Hans", "zh-Hant"];
    ocrRequest.recognitionLevel = .accurate
    ocrRequest.automaticallyDetectsLanguage = false
    ocrRequest.usesLanguageCorrection = false

